# Visualize Image Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, ndvi

I have created image collection in GEE of LANDSAT 7 NDVI (LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI). I chose date range and I know I have 71 images in the image collection.

Is there any way to clip all the image collection according to a shapefille I have and see them as layers? Should I build function that calls every image and visualize it?

I used filterBound and the code run but when I try to visualize even just one image it doesn't really filter it according to the shape. My end goal is to download all the NDVI images I have for that period clipped according to the shapefille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to clip your collection you can do something like that

```
var clippedCol=col.map(function(im){ 
   return im.clip(myGeometry);
});
```

but if it's to export all the images you can simply try something like that:

```
Export.image.toDrive({image:col.toBands(),
                  region:myGeometry,
                  scale:30});
```

Where you specify your geometry for the clip, and use toBands() to convert the stack of images as a single image with lot of bands.

Answer (score 1):

For clarification, `filterBounds` does not clip images, it only removes all images not intersect with the `bound`. If you want to clip every image in your collection, just use `map` and `clip` function as suggested in the first snippet of code suggested by Mathieu Gravey.

For exporting all NDVI images (there should be 71 of them, I guess), Mathieu Gravey's answer provides one good approach, but you may need to convert each band to a single image after exporting. There're two other approaches to export those NDVI images:

- If you don't mind clicking 71x2 = 142 times, you may use `col.map(function(img) { Export.image.toDrive({image: img, scale: 30, region: yourShapefile}) })` to export each NDVI image.
- Use Earth Engine Python API instead of JavaScript API. This will export every image without asking a single click.